# Django Internationalization

Tags: python, django

I have a similar issue as found here [Why doesn't Django produce locale files from template files in another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726623/why-doesnt-django-produce-locale-files-from-template-files-in-another-directory)

However I don't understand the solution. My structure:

```
Project
   App1
      locale
      templates
   App2
      locale
      templates
   templates
      somefilethatneedstranslation.html
```

Now when I run this command from App1:

```
python ../manage.py App1 -l nl
```

It nicely creates a po file for the App1 templates in the App1 locale folder

However I want my global templates to be translated aswell.. note: I do NOT want a locale folder in my project root, so I tried adding a symlink to the templates folder from App1 but it does not append the translation results to the App1/locale/po file

from the App1 folder

```
ln -s ../templates/locale/* translations
python ../manage.py App1 -l nl --symlinks
```

What am I missing?

note:

from the templates folder

```
python ../manage.py templates -l nl
```

could work, but it won't because obviously templates is not an installed app, it seems I am missing the obvious...

Comment: where do you want to store the translations for your global templates?

Comment: well django 1.4 alpha tells me locale folders in the project root are deprecated.. so anywhere else I suppose? It feels really odd that django doesn't provide an out-of-the-box method for global template translations?

Comment: what happens when you run "django-admin.py makemessages -l nl" from your project directory?

Comment: Error: This script should be run from the Django SVN tree or your project or app tree. If you did indeed run it from the SVN checkout or your project or application, maybe you are just missing the conf/locale (in the django tree) or locale (for project and application) directory? It is not created automatically, you have to create it by hand if you want to enable i18n for your project or application. Edit: Likely because there is no locale folder in my project root, but then again there shouldn't?

Comment: try to just create the locale folder in your project. you are saying that you do not care where your translations are, then why not put them in to "locale"?

Comment: well django 1.4 gives me a messages locale folder in the project root is not allowed (deprecated) so theres probably a reason to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full deprecation message (which is also explained in the [translation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations)) is:

> Translations in the project directory aren't supported anymore. LOCALE_PATHS setting instead.

This message is perhaps a bit unclear. While *automatic* discovery of translations in the project directory is deprecated, the use of `LOCALE_PATHS` to reference a project-level locale folder is totally acceptable.

If you have project-level templates, it doesn't make sense to have these templates translated in an app-specific locale location: keep a project-level locale directory, reference it in LOCALE_PATHS.

Comment: Thank you, guess I missed that part :)